# How to pick a season/month over several years from a pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, date-range

I've got a pandas dataframe with data over three consecutive years...
Is there an easy way to pick the summer/winter periods?

At the moment, I do this:

```
df_summer = df[((df.index.month > 5) & (df.index.month < 9))]
df_winter = df[((df.index.month < 3) | (df.index.month == 12))]
```

but from xarray I'm used to a notation like:

```
xa_summer = xa[xa.dt.season=='JJA']
```

for one year I could do:

```
df_summer = df['YYYYMMDDHH':'YYYYMMDDHH']
```

Is there a more intuitive way to pick a season over multiple years in pandas?

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not implemented in [pandas yet](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/7454).

One idea is create helper `season` by modulo by `12`, add `3`, floor divide by `3` and last `map` by dictionary:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=40, freq='MS')
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(40)}, index=rng)  
#print (df)

season = ((df.index.month % 12 + 3) // 3).map({1:'DJF', 2: 'MAM', 3:'JJA', 4:'SON'})
print (season)
Index(['MAM', 'JJA', 'JJA', 'JJA', 'SON', 'SON', 'SON', 'DJF', 'DJF', 'DJF',
       'MAM', 'MAM', 'MAM', 'JJA', 'JJA', 'JJA', 'SON', 'SON', 'SON', 'DJF',
       'DJF', 'DJF', 'MAM', 'MAM', 'MAM', 'JJA', 'JJA', 'JJA', 'SON', 'SON',
       'SON', 'DJF', 'DJF', 'DJF', 'MAM', 'MAM', 'MAM', 'JJA', 'JJA', 'JJA'],
      dtype='object')
```

---

```
df_summer = df[season == 'JJA']
print (df_summer)
             a
2017-06-01   1
2017-07-01   2
2017-08-01   3
2018-06-01  13
2018-07-01  14
2018-08-01  15
2019-06-01  25
2019-07-01  26
2019-08-01  27
2020-06-01  37
2020-07-01  38
2020-08-01  39

df_winter = df[season == 'DJF']
print (df_winter)
             a
2017-12-01   7
2018-01-01   8
2018-02-01   9
2018-12-01  19
2019-01-01  20
2019-02-01  21
2019-12-01  31
2020-01-01  32
2020-02-01  33
```

Or create new column:

```
df_summer = df[df['season'] == 'JJA']
print (df_summer)
             a season
2017-06-01   1    JJA
2017-07-01   2    JJA
2017-08-01   3    JJA
2018-06-01  13    JJA
2018-07-01  14    JJA
2018-08-01  15    JJA
2019-06-01  25    JJA
2019-07-01  26    JJA
2019-08-01  27    JJA
2020-06-01  37    JJA
2020-07-01  38    JJA
2020-08-01  39    JJA

df_winter = df[df['season'] == 'DJF']
print (df_winter)
             a season
2017-12-01   7    DJF
2018-01-01   8    DJF
2018-02-01   9    DJF
2018-12-01  19    DJF
2019-01-01  20    DJF
2019-02-01  21    DJF
2019-12-01  31    DJF
2020-01-01  32    DJF
2020-02-01  33    DJF
```

Another idea is use [`Index.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html) by months:

```
df_summer = df[df.index.month.isin([6,7,8])]
print (df_summer)
             a
2017-06-01   1
2017-07-01   2
2017-08-01   3
2018-06-01  13
2018-07-01  14
2018-08-01  15
2019-06-01  25
2019-07-01  26
2019-08-01  27
2020-06-01  37
2020-07-01  38
2020-08-01  39

df_winter = df[df.index.month.isin([12,1,2])]
print (df_winter)
             a
2017-12-01   7
2018-01-01   8
2018-02-01   9
2018-12-01  19
2019-01-01  20
2019-02-01  21
2019-12-01  31
2020-01-01  32
2020-02-01  33
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will probably use the Index.isin method but it's nice to have alternatives...